# In Ag-grid-react how to disable update button if edited cell is not valid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-validation

I'm trying to disable update button after validating cell editor
[image]

link for full code,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-complex-editor-3b7ybk?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FComponents%2FEditors%2FSimpleEditor.jsx,src%2FComponents%2FEditors%2FAsyncValidationEditor.jsx,src%2Folympic_lists.js,src%2Fcolumns.js,src%2Futils.js,src%2FApp.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the renderer - ActionsRenderer

- expose a method for updating the button state.

  - To do this, use **forwardRef** and **useImperativeHandle**
- and I added a separate state **updateDisabled** so other buttons are not affected by the state change ie "cancel"

Below are the changes I made.

```
export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
...
  let [updateDisabled, setUpdateDisabled] = useState(false);
...
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    exposedUpdateDisabled: setUpdateDisabled,
  }));
})
```

In the validator - AsyncValidationEditor(or whatever editor you plan to use)

- get the instance of the actions renderer and update the renderer in your validator logic.

  ```
    export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    ...
      useEffect(() => {
    ...
        new Promise(...)
          .then((valid) => {
            setValid(valid);
            setValidating(false);

            // get actions renderer for this row
            const actionInstance = 
              props.api.getCellRendererInstances({
              rowNodes: [props.node],
              columns: ['actions'],
            })[0].componentInstance;

            // use exposed api to update state on the renderer
            actionInstance.exposedUpdateDisabled(!valid);
    ...
     }, [debouncedInputVal]);
  ```

  })

here is **your updated code**  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-complex-editor-5xr8na?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FComponents%2FEditors%2FSimpleEditor.jsx,src%2FComponents%2FEditors%2FAsyncValidationEditor.jsx,src%2Folympic_lists.js,src%2Fcolumns.js,src%2Futils.js,src%2FComponents%2FRenderers%2FActionsRenderer.jsx